# Windows 8 consuming above 100 GB space?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I have Windows 8 OS which came with my Acer laptop. When I bought my
laptop, it consumes nearly 40 to 50 gb space in my hard-drive, but now
it consumes above 100gb space. I have updated my OS several times, is
there any method so that I can reduce size of my OS?

Comment: How did you determine that Windows is what consumes the storage device. Even with every single update released to date 40GB is exessive.  Are we talking about Windows 8.1 or Windows 8.0.  Windows Cleanup tool might be helpful to run.

Comment: I’d say that the size is probably including `WinSxS` which effectively doubles the reported size, but they are presumably checking in the same way as they did when they first got it, so obviously it has increased from 50GB to 100GB. Ankit, what do you mean by “updated your OS”?

Comment: I'm sorry... do you mean that your **C:\Windows** directory is 100GB big? Or that 100GB of space is used on your hard drive and you actually have no idea what is using it? 100GB space used sounds like Windows + a bunch of programs + a bunch of files (or a bunch of games)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot for the solution about the missing space having about 100 Gb hidden somewhere on the partition. I found the true solution. I am using Windows 8. No fancy software used to solve this.

Disabling, deleting or resizing the System Protection value helped a little bit, a drop in the ocean.

Using WinDirStat helped to see which folder used the most space. BUT really... where is the difference of 100 GB? Where is my space?

It was used by Volume Shadow Copy Service... If you want to know more about Volume Shadow Copy Service just Google about it.

Here is what I did to get back my 100 GB:

I opened an elevated Command Prompt (type `Command Prompt` in the Start Menu's search box, right click on it and select Run as Administrator).

Type this there:

```
VSSADMIN LIST SHADOWSTORAGE
```

and press Enter

You will see where your stolen space is ;) I ONLY had 100 GB! Only! The partition size was 232 GB and I had about 42 GB free. Someone was constantly stealing space... but who?

In my case was the C: partition, so I just typed these:

```
vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=C: /on=C: /maxsize=10GB
```

Forcing the system to resize the shadow storage allocation to maximum of 10 GB. Chose another value if you want.

Ok, but my space didn't come back yet. The last command to get it back was the following (but be aware that you will delete all the shadow storage. I didn't cared about it. Read about this on Google before type the command and blame me after! Read about Volume Shadow Copy Service if it helps you or not).

```
vssadmin delete shadows /all
```

and Shazammm... my 100 GB came back.

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that your OS grew so much, what you are seeing is all additional programs that you have loaded taking up addition space. According to [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements) Windows 8 needs "Hard disk space: 16 GB (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)"

Comment: `what you are seeing is all additional programs that you have loaded` …or games. Games are *huge* these days. I remember when amazing games could fit on a floppy disk… with room to spare. ¬_¬